# Displaying two dates in one cell

Tags: excel

I am trying to display two dates in one cell in Excel.

I have used the formula :

```
=DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()), I1) & " & " & DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),I15)
```

Where the values of I1 and I15 are 1 and 15 respectively. The reason I chose this formula is because I want each date to display the 1st and the 15th of the current month. I would like this cell to read "7/1/12 & 7/15/12" however right now the current formula is giving me "41091 & 41105" I have formated the cell to display the correct date format that I want. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Use the Text() function:

```
=TEXT(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),I1),"mm/dd/yyyy") & " & " & TEXT(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),I15), "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

The second parameter controls how the data should be formatted.  Valid values can be found [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx).

Comment: Beat me to it; alternatively, if you don't want the leading zeroes for month and day, use the format `m/d/yyyy`.

Answer (score 3):

I have just had this problem. This is the general solution:

```
=TEXT(NOW();"MM.YY")
&" - "&
TEXT(NOW();"MM.YY")
```

It returns this:
`04.17 - 04.17`

Answer (score 2):

A slightly shorter alternative:

```
=TEXT(NOW()-DAY(NOW())+I1,"m/d/yy")&" & "&TEXT(NOW()-DAY(NOW())+I15,"m/d/yy")
```

*Update*. even shorter:

```
=TEXT(NOW(),"m/"""&I1&"""/yy & m/"""&I15&"""/yy")
```

Comment: Great! that worked. I just have one last small question. So I used the formula you posted and it displayed the two dates "7/1/12 & 7/15/12" I changed the date of the second date to 7/25/12 so that it read "7/1/12 & 7/25/12" Now, I have used conditiona formatting for this cell to highlight when the date is within a week before or after the displayed date. Now for some reason it cannot recognize and highlight this cell now that it has two dates displayed. Is there a way I can get excel to recognize that one of the two dates is within the one week range and highlight the cell? Thanks again!

Comment: If you want a conditional formatting formula based on the days of the month in I1 or I15 falling within a week of today's day of month, maybe try: `=OR(ABS(DAY(TODAY())-I15)<7,ABS(DAY(TODAY())-I1)<7)`

Comment: So I am using the conditional formatiing dropdown and going >> manage rules >> New Rule >> Format only cells that contain >> then doing cell value, equal to, and the formula you have posted but somehow it is not working. Am I doing something wrong here? Again.. Thank you so much you have been a huge help!

Comment: You need to select *Use a Formula to Determine Which Cells to Format* under *New Rule* then choose an appropriate format. You can test the formula in another cell and make any necessary modifications there before applying it as I wasn't totally clear on your requirements.

Comment: Yes, the formula looks very good. What I have is a column of many dates, with some cells containing more than one date, and I would like the cells to highlight when they are within a week of the surrent date. So if one column has for example the dates 7/1/12 and 7/25/12 and current date is 7/27/12 I want this cell to be highlighted becasue there is atleast one date in that cell that is within a week (before or after) the current date. The problem only arises with cells that contain more than one date. All cells that only contain one date highlight and function properly but ones with >2 don't

Comment: Suppose your date formula is in B3. It sounds like you need to change the conditional formatting formula to refer to the formula result. One way might be to replace `I1` by `DAY(LEFT(B3,FIND("&",B3&"&")-1))` and `I15` by `TEXT(REPLACE(B3,1,FIND("&",B3&"&")+1,""),"d;;;-\7")` so that the second condition is ignored if there's only one date in the cell. You can test these two formulas in other cells before implementing.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have a date format on a cell and have two dates listed.  The format of the cell needs to be set to text or general. and then format the dates as text  see below

```
=TEXT(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),I1), "m/d/y") & " & " &TEXT( DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),I15),"m/d/y")
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I wanted a week to week entry, from 2 weeks ago to 1 week ago;
Shows up as I wanted it to;  `MM/DD/YYYY` to `MM/DD/YYYY`

```
=TEXT(NOW()-14&DAY(NOW()),"m/d/yy")&" to "&TEXT(NOW()-7&DAY(NOW()),"m/d/yy")
```

Comment: That's definitely the way to do it but he asked for the 1st and 15th of each month, not one and two weeks ago.