# how to add a dash between two dates, on same cell, from another sheet on excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to add a "-" between two dates on excel. The two dates are on sheet two, and on sheet one, I want to basically create a date range as mm-dd-yy - mm-dd-yy.

I tried to use text function, but I can't format the date as mm-dd-yy,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673847/displaying-two-dates-in-one-cell

Answer (score 3):

Convert the date in to text, By using TEXT function. And then try to concatenate.

=CONCAT(TEXT(A1,"mm-dd-yyyy"),"-",TEXT(A2,"mm-dd-yyyy"))